# Javascript integer to datetime with specific timezone

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, serialization

I have the following datetime saved in an SQL Server 2005 database: `2012-12-06 16:20:11.010`.

I want to display this datetime using javascript on the client side, so I serialize it (as part of a larger object) using `System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode`, which runs the following code:

```
internal static readonly long DatetimeMinTimeTicks = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).Ticks;

private static void SerializeDateTime(DateTime datetime, StringBuilder sb, JavaScriptSerializer.SerializationFormat serializationFormat)
{
    if (serializationFormat == JavaScriptSerializer.SerializationFormat.JSON)
    {
        sb.Append("\"\\/Date(");
        sb.Append((datetime.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - JavaScriptSerializer.DatetimeMinTimeTicks) / 10000L);
        sb.Append(")\\/\"");
        return;
    }
    sb.Append("new Date(");
    sb.Append((datetime.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - JavaScriptSerializer.DatetimeMinTimeTicks) / 10000L);
    sb.Append(")");
}
```

On the client side, I convert it into a datetime object like so: ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mansfield/4SWwj/))

```
var strDate = "/Date(1354828811010)/"; //value returned by above function
var re = /-?\d+/;
var m = re.exec(strDate);            
var date = new Date(parseInt(m[0]));
```

On a PC with the timezone set to Eastern Standard, this time appears correctly as `Thu Dec 06 2012 16:20:11 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`. However, on a pc with the timezone as GMT-6, it returns as `Thu Dec 06 2012 15:20:11 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)`.

This time is correct as `Thu Dec 06 2012 16:20:11 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)`, but I'm not sure how to best display it correctly. I don't need to actually display the timezone, I just need it to show up as 16:20:11 regardless of the user's local timezone settings.

Is there a mechanism in javascript to let me force a date to a specific timezone? The research I've done on it suggests there isn't.

Otherwise, if I need to make a change server side, what's my best bet?

Comment: I guess you mean [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is related to what is described in [Moment.js issue 611](https://github.com/timrwood/moment/issues/611).  If so, would you please add your feedback to this issue?  It is certainly a showstopper for me.

BTW - I looked at DateJS and XDate also, and as far as I can tell, none have this functionality.  JavaScript seems locked in at either UTC or the local timezone of the browser.

Also, Moment.js already handles the Microsoft date format that `JavaScriptSerializer` emits, so you can use it directly.  However, I would strongly recommend using [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) instead.  Even Microsoft is using this now.  It will return dates in ISO format by default.

Comment: Yes, that looks similar to my issue. What I ended up doing (for now) is just converting the time to UTC server-side, that way at least the correct time will always display locally based on the user's local timezone. It's not exactly what I wanted, but it's a suitable workaround. I'll keep an eye on that moment issue - that may be of use the next time this comes up. Thanks for the library suggestion as well - I'm not going to refactor my current project but I've got a new one coming up, I'll be sure to try out JSON.Net for that!

Comment: FYI - [MomentJS 2.1.0](http://momentjs.com/)  was recently released, along with the moment-timezone addon.  You should take another look. :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Moments.js](http://momentjs.com/), it is one of a number of javascript date libraries that can help you with your date/time requirements.

others include [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) and [Xdate](http://arshaw.com/xdate/)

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.ToUniversalTime() is going to include the timezone in the serialized value and javascript is going to read it. If you don't want that to happen don't serialize it with the timezone. Just use the DateTime.toString() method and give it a simple format string like:

```
datetime.toString("o");
```

which will output something like

```
2008-06-15T21:15:07.0000000
```

Comment: That's not my code there, that's what `System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode` is doing.